# Methods of taking notes from home and work with text and images

Tags: html, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown, github-pages

I am looking for somewhere to create notes with images for myself. Anything like Evernote, Onenote, google docs, onedrive, that kind of thing. I have a massive limitation in that my workplace blocks absolutely everything like this that they can, and I'd really love to be able to make notes at work or at home. That pretty much rules everything out. The one little thing that I can do is to use the github portal from work (not sure if that is by design or not, and I dare not ask in case it is not by design!) Unfortunately it doesn't really lend itself to making some notes with a few images here and there - it's just for text really that I can see. The two ideas that I have been mulling over are Jupyter notebooks uploaded to github, and Github pages. I think that either of these could be a good solution, but neither is perfect and there is a pretty big learning curve (especially with Github pages). Before I invest some big time and effort here, I thought I would ask to see if anyone might know of an easier way? All I want is to be able to write some notes and bung a few pictures on the same page, next to the notes. Nothing fancy. I have concentrated on things around github so far as that's something that is available to me from work.

Any ideas?
Thanks so much for any ideas or help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like https://keep.google.com will be the perfect solution as it is on the Google domain and surely they wont block Google.

It is a really easy to use interface which allows you to add images and text, reminders, color coding and labels. I find it really useful as it will also sync.

You can also look at Zoho Notebook. Also free and available as an app as well. Check it out here - https://www.zoho.com/notebook/

For your requirements I would suggest Google Keep however.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Brian. I've just tried them both, and they're both blocked from work I'm afraid :(

Comment: oh wow, that sucks, they really strict :). If I think of another solution will share..